# MS-Access: Querying data in an existing table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to create a query in MS-Access that will lookup an exiting table and produce a particular result. Here is an example of the existing table, let's call it tblA:

```
C1  C2  
1   Balloon
2   Tree
1   Bike
1   Tree
2   Balloon
2   Kite
1   Clown
1   Balloon
```

The query I'm trying to write will look at tblA, view column C2 and produce a result that will show values greater than 1. Here is my desired result of the query:

```
C2
Balloon
Tree
```

**Explanation of the expected output** : What I'm trying to accomplish is if values in C1 share the same value in C2, I wan't the query to display the shared C2 value. For example, C1 represents companies such as KFC and McDonalds. C2 represents work dates. If KFC and McDonalds share the same work date (e.g. Dec 1, 2017), I want the query to display only the work date, i.e. Dec 1, 2017.

I'm a rookie at this stuff, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'll want a condition after the WHERE clause to filter WHERE C1 > 1.
SELECT DISTINCT C2 WHERE C1 > 1. Also your output will include Kite because its' C1 value is > 1.

Comment: @xhermit that seems like a full answer, not a comment (it may be simple but it still fully answers the question). Please post it as such (note that it's unclear to me if it's the right one, because the question doesn't specify if C1 should be >1, or if `Count(C2)` should be >1

Comment: I'll try to better explain my situation by stating it in another context. C1 contains contractors, such as FedEx and Canada Post. C2 contains delivery dates. I would like the query to display delivery dates that both contractors share. For example, both contractors are delivering a package on Dec 1, 2017, so the query will only display the Dec 1, 2017 date. I hope that better explains my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
select distinct A.C2 from tblA A
join tblA B on A.C2 = B.C2 and A.C1 <> B.C1
```

Comment: Thank you. What I'm trying to accomplish is if values in C1 share the same value in C2, I wan't the query to display the shared C2 value.

For example, C1 represents companies such as KFC and McDonalds. C2 represents work dates. If KFC and McDonalds share the same work date (e.g. Dec 1, 2017), I want the query to display only the work date, i.e. Dec 1, 2017.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
SELECT Count(tblA.C1) AS CountOfC1, tblA.C2
FROM tblA
GROUP BY tblA.C2
HAVING (((Count(tblA.C1))>1));
```

Comment: That's a lot of parentheses here: `(((Count(tblA.C1))>1))`. Any specific reason for it?

Comment: No, not really.... they were generated by the query designer... other than wrapping the 'Count' argument, all the others could be removed.  If I have a very complex 'where' clause, sometimes they are helpful  :))

Comment: That's precisely why I stopped using the designer, it's 3 opening and closing parentheses too many in my opinion, it clutters code and makes it harder to understand

Comment: I use the designer mainly due to the speed limitations imposed by typing with two fingers. But as I mentioned, if I'm working with a complex 'Where' clause with many 'And','Or', or arithmetic, etc., it lets me simplify the grouping and order. Sure wish I'd taken that typing course back in the 60's!